unpack requires a buffer of X bytes
        field_names = []
        for i in range(obj["fields_cnt"]):
            print(i)
            name_len = struct.unpack('H', f.read(2))[0]
            print(type(name_len))
            print(type(f.read(name_len)))
            print(name_len)
            field_names.append(
                struct.unpack('<{0}s'.format(name_len), f.read(name_len))[0].decode('latin-1').strip('\x00'))
        print("FIELD NAMES:")
        print(field_names)

Error:
output:
line 57, in main
    struct.unpack('<{0}s'.format(name_len), f.read(name_len))[0].decode('latin-1').strip('\x00'))
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 28261 bytes

I tried using the calculate() function, but result is the same.
I really don’t know what to do.. help

It would be helpful if you could edit your question to make the code to be a Minimal, Reproducible Example and also include the full transcript of the the output of the run. If I make some assumptions about your data, it looks like the f.read(name_len))being executed in theprintstatement is moving the pointer forward such that the nextf.read` is not at the expected place.

The problem is that you are passing a single element of the read bytes into the unpack - when you do  f.read(name_len))[0].decode('latin-1').strip('\x00'), the [0] there picks just the first byte from the data that have been read.
It would be expecting 28261 bytes of data.
Besides that you are converting that one byte into a text string (text) - it would expect bytes. It makes no sense to call .decode on bytes to read from a file to pass to struct.unpack.
Then you call strip on the data: you are reading a  binary file, with the amount of data explicited in  the two header bytes. If there was any byte to be stripped with the .strip call, it would make the data shorter, and you would get the same error again.
And finally, struct.unpack with an s data type will just consume the indicte amount of bytes of the input buffer and return a byte string with those bytes. An s field as the sole field in such a call is essentially a no-operation: you can just use directly the bytes read from the file to start with.
So, in this single line there are  4 conceptual errors, one after the other - just do:
`field_names.append(f.read(name_len))'  and you should be good. Call decode on the data read if those are supposed to be text, and not a byte string.

If I make some assumptions about the incoming data for your code, it looks like the line print(type(f.read(name_len))) is reading the text of expected length and moving the cursor to after that data in the file. This means when you do the next f.read(name_len) it is reading from after where the expected text data is in the file and giving you an error.
For the example data I used, the error was fixed when I removed the print statement with the f.read.
Also, as you are only unpacking one type of data at a time with struct.unpack, your code may be easier to read if you did not use the struct module.
For example, I did the following test:
import io


f = io.BytesIO(b"\x08\x00field1\x00\x00\x06\x00field2")

obj = {'fields_cnt': 2}


def main():
    field_names = []
    for i in range(obj["fields_cnt"]):
        print(f"Fields Count: {i}")
        raw_len = f.read(2)
        name_len = int.from_bytes(raw_len, byteorder="little")
        print(f"\tname len raw: {type(raw_len)}, {raw_len}")
        print(f"\tName Len: {type(name_len)}, {name_len}")
        raw_field_name = f.read(name_len)
        print(f"\tRaw String Data: {type(raw_field_name)}, {raw_field_name}")
        field_names.append(raw_field_name.decode("latin-1").rstrip("\x00"))
    print(f"FIELD NAMES: {field_names}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Which gave the following output:
Fields Count: 0
    name len raw: <class 'bytes'>, b'\x08\x00'
    Name Len: <class 'int'>, 8
    Raw String Data: <class 'bytes'>, b'field1\x00\x00'
Fields Count: 1
    name len raw: <class 'bytes'>, b'\x06\x00'
    Name Len: <class 'int'>, 6
    Raw String Data: <class 'bytes'>, b'field2'
FIELD NAMES: ['field1', 'field2']

